# This database is apparently really big?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

First of all, I must apologise for the onslaught I've given the Access tag over the past few days. It's nothing like MS-SQL :(

OK, I have a small working table that contains 3,500 records. I'm trying to prune them down to a specific set that needs modification to fit our migration app.

I started with

```
SELECT tempMainTab.*
FROM tempMainTab INNER JOIN tempCritTab 
ON tempMainTab.[LINK] <> tempCritTab.[LINK]
```

Which is ok, right? (right?)

But of course, nothing ever works first time:

> *The query cannot be completed. Either the size of the query 
>   result is larger than the maximum size of a database (2GB) or there is not 
>   enough temporary storage space on the disk to store the query result.*

So, I closed the existing window of tempCritTab that I had open, and tried again.

Nope:

> *Access cannot read the table. The table may be corrupt or may not exist.*

(Or something along those lines)

So, I tried the Compact/Repair tool. That appeared to work... kinda.
Now, instead of the expected 1,200 rows, I get ***7,125,920*** rows!?
Now I've just tried to run the query again. No dice - same error as the first.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you really want:

```
SELECT tempMainTab.*
FROM tempMainTab LEFT JOIN
     tempCritTab 
     ON tempMainTab.[LINK] = tempCritTab.[LINK]
WHERE tempCritTab.[LINK] IS NULL;
```

This gets the rows in the main table that are not in the crit table -- reverse the order if you want the logic the other way around.

Your version essentially produces a cartesian product of the two tables.

Comment: Holy smidge, no wonder my laptop hit thermal shutdown. Much appreciated.